# ElasticSearch not returning expected results

Tags: json, elasticsearch

I am attempting to run an ElasticSearch search using the following query.  Please pardon my ignorance, as I'm new to ES, and I've sorta cobbled this together by trial and error trying to follow the documentation.  Basically, the only parts that are working as expected are the from, size, sort, and the match on severity.  Thank you in advance for the assist!

```
{
  "from":0,
  "size":50,
  "sort":{"timestamp":{"order":"desc"}},
  "query":[
      {
        "range":{
          "timestamp":{"gte":"2013-11-18T05:00:00+00:00","lte":"2013-12-02T05:00:00+00:00"}
        }
      },
      {
        "query":{
          "match":{"severity":{"query":"medium","operator":"or"}}
        }
      },
      {
        "query":{
          "constantScore":{
            "filter":{
              "query":{
                "query_string":{"default_field":"_all","query":"10.1.10.22"}
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Your question doesn't have enough details. What is your data? What are you trying to do? What are you expecting? What do you get back? Include samples for these; best to include requests to insert data sample.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of detail.  My goal is to return data based on input from a user.  The user would supply the start/end date, the severity (low, medium, and high), and a search keyword.  I'm receiving results, but not filtered the way I would expect.  It appears that all date ranges are being returned, as well as the results not being filtered by the string in the query_string query.

Comment: You need to read Query DSL of ES in order to write a correct query. You query is totally wrong. In your case, you will need a query to query "search keyword", and some filters to filter "start/end", "serverity". Both can be performed in a search request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to read more about Query DSL. Here's the correct query based on your input:

```
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "default_field": "_all",
      "query": "10.1.10.22"
    }
  },
  "filter": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "range": {
            "timestamp": {
              "gte": "2013-11-18T05:00:00+00:00",
              "lte": "2013-12-02T05:00:00+00:00"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "severity": "medium"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

The above query can be explained as:
- filter the data first using bool filter, "must" here can be understood as "AND". So the data will be filter by "timestamp in range..." AND "serverity=medium"
- then search the filtered data using "query_string"
That will make your searching much more faster.

Comment: Duc - thank you so much.  That really got me going on the right track. I wasn't clear on this, but the user can select multiple severities.  So the user might submit "medium" and "low" as the severities on which they want to search.  I changed your "term" filter to:

`{"match":{"severity":{"query":"medium low","operator":"or"}}}`

Please forgive the formatting on that, I can't seem to get it to look right.  But as you see, I'm trying to use the "match" filter instead of "term".  I get the following error:

No filter registered for [match]];

Help one last time?  Thanks!

Comment: I just referenced the docs, I was looking in the wrong section - filter doesn't have a "match" query.  So I am instead trying to use a "should" filter:
`"should":[{"term":{"severity":"medium"}},{"term":{"severity":"low"}}]`

However, with this I get `Parse Failure [No parser for element [term]]];`  Any clues?

Comment: Last update.  I had the "should" filter outside the "bool".  I moved it inside, and all is good.  Thanks Duc.  Voting you up, and I'd do it twice if I could!

Comment: glad that it help. If you need to use query as a filter, like "match" in this case, you can use the "query filter", it will let you define a query as a filter http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-filter.html

Answer (score 0):

In any case, your query is not formatted correctly. If you want to combine multiple queries you can use the bool query. See the docs: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html